# Db2 get values which are not present in list

Tags: sql, db2

I have a hardcoded list of ids ex. 1,2,3. I want to get list of ids that are not present in database. Ex. Database have 1,2 so expected result is 3.
Database is read only so I cannot use values clause.

Comment: "Database is read only so I cannot use values clause."  I don't understand this.  DB2 doesn't support a values clause in a select query.

Comment: Sample solution with values clause can be found on stackoverflow id 42654956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DB2 you can create a derived table with values using `sysibm.sysdummy1`.  So one method is:

```
select id
from (select 1 as id from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 
     ) x
except
select id
from t;
```

Comment: DB2 does support the `values ()` clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=519cc064b8160fb0bae7800db2677730